# Logarithmic steps inside a Do

Tags: functions, physics, scripting, data-structures

I have trouble, i need to do several computations inside a loop using values in a logaritmic scale, is this possible?[image]

Inside of the cicle i create a several data sctructures, and it currently works fine using the typical delimitations {i,0,1,0.0001}, but my goal is to have more computations around 0.

Comment: you can pass a list of values for iterator, e.g. `Do[Echo[i], {i, {0.0, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0}}]`

Comment: I often use something like `i := 10^ip; Do[Echo[i], {ip, -3, 3}]`, but maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to construct the values of the iterator explicitly. For example:

```
Table[i, {i, Exp[Range[0, 1, 0.01]] - 1}]
```

has lots of values near zero and progresively fewer at larger values. Of course, if you want a function $f$ of these, it's straightforward:

```
Table[f[i], {i, Exp[Range[0, 1, 0.02]] - 1}]
```

And of course, Do uses the same iterator structure as Table.